# Pinch Zoom gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I'd like to implement a GridView with Pinch Zoom. for example, if we zoom on an area the number of cells will decrease.

I'm trying to do this with a GridView because each cell should be clickable for doing a different action.
Is there any interface I need to implement? Is it possible to get this result with an ImageView? How would you do it? Code would be appreciated.